# Adding code to URL that will adjust DIV through jQuery

Tags: jquery, url, html, hide, show

I have this code as an example:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
     $('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
               $(this).show(200);
          }
          else {
               $(this).hide(600);
          }
     });
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

             <div style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: #99CCFF; padding: 5px; width: 150px;">
                <a id="myHeader1" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes1');" >show this one only</a>
             </div>
             <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCCC; display: block;padding: 5px; width: 150px;">Div #1</div>


             <div style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: #99CCFF; padding: 5px; width: 150px;">
                <a id="myHeader2" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes2');" >show this one only</a>
             </div>
             <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes2" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCCC; display: none;padding: 5px; width: 150px;">Div #2</div>

             <div style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: #99CCFF; padding: 5px; width: 150px;">
                <a id="myHeader3" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes3');" >show this one only</a>
             </div>
             <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes3" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCCC; display: none;padding: 5px; width: 150px;">Div #3</div>

</body>
</html>
```

On a different page, I want to have a link that will show **Div #2** when the user loads the page by clicking that external link. I want this to be possible by adding a hash variable to the URL, for instance: domain.com/page.html#newboxes2

Someone told me that such feature is possible by playing around this with:

```
$(function(){

  switch( window.location.hash ){
    case '#showcontainer1':
      $('#container1').fadeIn();
      break;
    default:
      $('#container2').fadeIn()
      break;
  }

});
```

However, after trying to wrap my head around how to add that code to my own code, I could not make it work. How does this work?

Any assistance is appreciate, my knowledge of coding is very limited so please be detailed if you choose to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your current html structure, all you will need to do is this. Navigating to `domain.com/page.html#newboxes2` will result in the `<div>` with id as `#newboxes2` will be shown. As you did before, set all of them to `display:none;` by default. You should consider pulling your styling out of the html and instead put them all between `<style>` tags at the top of your page. You can use class selectors (e.g. `.newboxes`) to apply the same style to all elements of a particular class.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eqPGW/4/

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    var showBox = window.location.hash.indexOf('#newboxes') != -1;
    if(showBox) {
        $(window.location.hash).prev('.cover').hide();
        $(window.location.hash).show();
    }
    else {
        $('.cover').first().hide();
        $('.newboxes').first().show();   
    }

    $('.cover a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $cover = $(this).closest('.cover');
        $cover.hide();
        $('.cover').not($cover).show();
        $('.newboxes').hide();
        $cover.next('.newboxes').show();            
    });
});
```

HTML/CSS:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // PUT SCRIPT HERE
    </script>
    <style>
        .newboxes {
            border: 1px solid black;
            background-color: #CCCCCC;
            display: none;
            padding: 5px;
            width: 150px;
        }
        .cover {
        border: 1px solid blue; background-color: #99CCFF; padding: 5px; width: 150px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
     <div class="cover">
        <a id="myHeader1" href="#" >show this one only</a>
     </div>
     <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes1">Div #1</div>

     <div class="cover" >
        <a id="myHeader2" href="#" >show this one only</a>
     </div>
     <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes2">Div #2</div>

     <div class='cover' >
        <a id="myHeader3" href="#" >show this one only</a>
     </div>
     <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes2">Div #3</div>        

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This did not work. I added this code, then tried domain.com/index.html#newboxes3 but it did not show the newboxes3 div, have you tried this yourself?

Comment: Just saw your edit, the style works perfectly, but the URL solution that I was looking for does not function as proposed. Does it work for you?

Comment: Would this work although the page is PHP? E.g. index.php#newboxes3 ?

Comment: @henrik It operates at the dom level, when it's basically dealing with html anyway. Are you sure jQuery is included correctly? At the top of your jQuery dom ready function put `alert(window.location.href);` and see if that fires correctly

Comment: Yes jQuery is working fine as otherwise I would not be able to show/hide the divs by clicking on them. I am confused as to why this is not functioning properly.

Comment: Did the page alert `#newboxes3` when it loaded (I was checking that hash was set correctly)? Also, try opening your browser's javascript console and checking for any errors (somewhere like tools > web dev. > console) in firefox

Comment: Please have a look at this code: http://pastebin.com/KB2VTDmZ if you try it, it appears that it hides all the divs besides one. Note that I wanted to show one of them but leave the option for the user to click the other manually. If you see my original code and try that one out, you will understand my issue.

Comment: If you paste my original code in a file and see how it looks visually, that is exactly how I want it to be, but with different divs being selected depending on the URL. I hope I am making sense. My apologies if this appears confusing.

Comment: @henrik Sorry, I was misunderstanding your requirement, get it now. See update http://jsfiddle.net/eqPGW/4/ p.s. notice that I changed your `<a>` tag href's to just be `"#"`; putting javascript in the html like that is bad practice

Comment: Without question, one of the best assistance I have received on this site so far, works perfectly, thank you kindly.

Comment: @henrik no problem, glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually pretty straight-forward. The "hash" in a URL is the `#foo` bit; `window.location.hash` merely returns this bit from the URL. The code you received is kind of ridiculous though. The default functionality of the hash is to make the browser jump to that particular id in the page. If javascript is disabled, you'd still want it to jump, so you shouldn't use some arbitrary hash like `#showcontainer1` in the URL, but the actual id itself, `#container1`. Then, you don't need the switch statement, you just directly show this div.

```
if (window.location.hash) {
    $(window.location.hash).show();
}
```